# Get subrange in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, range

I'm trying to compute the average of values in a range, but not including the lowest value. What I'd like to do is something like:

```
=AVERAGE(SUBRANGE(SORT(A1:A10,1,FALSE), 1, 9))
```

Essentially, this would sort descending, then take the subrange consisting of all but the last element in the now-sorted range, and average that subrange. However, I can't find a function that has the functionality of `SUBRANGE` or figure out a way to mimick it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may have several occurrences of the minimum;

I suggest (a1+a2+...+a10 - min)/9:

```
=(SUM(A1:A10)-MIN(A1:A10))/(COUNT(A1:A10)-1)
```

Comment: (I edited your answer with a more generic version that I went with)

Answer (score 0):

one way would be to create a new range without the lowest value(s) using filter and then take the average of that:

```
=average(filter(A1:A10, A1:A10<>min(A1:A10)))
```

See if that works ?

Comment: It works in my testsheet: https://docs.google.com/a/open-school.be/spreadsheets/d/1jtxW64telWDar3BOTLz0nZgef1NFBatOkvwsvdtDInk/edit?usp=sharing. It yields the same result as Jjoao's formula BUT in case you have the lowest value two times (or more) I believe the result of Jjoao's formula is wrong. See sheet I shared.

Comment: I don't have permissions to see that.

Comment: The problem is that yours drops all of the values which are the minimum. What I'm looking for is dropping a single value. So if the range includes [1, 1, 2, 3], I want an average over [1, 2, 3], not over [2, 3].

Comment: Okay... That's indeed not how I understood your question. Good you already have a working solution. Cheers, JP